# How to implement seekg/seekpos on an in-memory buffer?

Tags: c++, buffer, iostream

Combining [this answer on in-memory streams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13059195/476820) with [this answer on `seekoff`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35066835/476820), I implemented an in-memory buffer as follows:

```
struct membuf : std::streambuf {
    membuf(char const* base, size_t size) {
        char* p(const_cast<char*>(base));
        this->setg(p, p, p + size);
    }
};
struct imemstream : virtual membuf, std::istream {
    imemstream(char const* base, size_t size) :
        membuf(base, size),
        std::istream(static_cast<std::streambuf*>(this)) {
    }

    std::iostream::pos_type seekoff(std::iostream::off_type off,
                                    std::ios_base::seekdir dir,
                                    std::ios_base::openmode which = std::ios_base::in) {
        if (dir == std::ios_base::cur) gbump(off);
        return gptr() - eback();
    }
};
```

However, [as explained in the comments of the first aswer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13059195/4768205#comment50305398_13059195), we still need to get `seekg`/`seekpos` working. So how to correctly implement `seekpos` here?

PS [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3488153/476820) goes in the same direction, but gives a more specific answer.

Comment: if your stream buffer is a simple memory buffer, then seekpos should simply set the current read-position pointer/index. I see that you don't have those. By default seekg this is a NOP in a basic_streambuf because not all stream buffers support the idea of seeking (imagine a network byte stream). So you'll need to add more code to maintain your own "current read position" and return that from gptr() etc

Comment: @RichardHodges _Maintaining_ the position doesn't seem to be a problem: `seekoff` returns the correct result. Rather, I don't know how to _set_  the position. So what I'm looking for is "simply set the current read-position pointer/index" in C++ code.

Comment: I think you have to implement and maintain these positions in your streambuf-derived class

Comment: @RichardHodges The position is definitely maintained already in `gptr()`. It works. It correctly increments and everything. So it is maintained somehow already by the base class. I'm looking for the code to correctly change the `gptr` value.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/setg

Comment: Alright, I've got `setg(eback(), eback() + sp, egptr())` now as body of `seekpos`. Is that all there is to it?

Comment: I think that's the crux of it. Whether that's *all* there is to it, I doubt. A good place to look would be the source code of the sinks and sources in boost::iostreams, which model std::streambuf.

Answer (score 11):

Since this hasn't been answered, I'm posting the implementation proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35066207).

```
pos_type seekpos(pos_type sp, std::ios_base::openmode which) override {
  return seekoff(sp - pos_type(off_type(0)), std::ios_base::beg, which);
}
```

Also, the implementation of `seekoff` did not work for me in the case of other directions. Consider amending it by the following:

```
pos_type seekoff(off_type off,
                 std::ios_base::seekdir dir,
                 std::ios_base::openmode which = std::ios_base::in) override {
  if (dir == std::ios_base::cur)
    gbump(off);
  else if (dir == std::ios_base::end)
    setg(eback(), egptr() + off, egptr());
  else if (dir == std::ios_base::beg)
    setg(eback(), eback() + off, egptr());
  return gptr() - eback();
}
```